# Azure DevOps - Test coverage for dotnet and js

Tags: azure-devops

Our solution contains a frontend react app along with a backend C# dotnet API. I can get code coverage generated for each project but not sure how to display the results in devops, is it even possible to display test coverage from multiple languages?

Everything in the MS docs only refers to one language at a time. How do other people handle this, do you have separate pipelines for the js side and dotnet side?

I'm thinking of publish the static files to an azure webapp unless devops can handle this?

Comment: Just add multiple publish test results steps, one for each different set of test results that are in different formats and locations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is it even possible to display test coverage from multiple languages?

If you want to show both code coverages at the same time in the runs' summary, this is not currently supported, it only shows the code coverage of the last test.

However, you are able to get both coverages in the artifacts published using [Publish Code Coverage Results task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/test/publish-code-coverage-results?view=azure-devops#q--a).

It is important to note that you need to publish code coverage results after each test. According to Microsoft's document:

> It does not merge coverage data. If you provide multiple files as
> input to the task, only the first match is considered. If you use
> multiple publish code coverage tasks in the pipeline, the summary and
> report is shown for the last task. Any previously uploaded data is
> ignored.

Comment: Hi Jane, thanks for the response, I may go down the route of having separate pipelines for displaying these results for now.